# Scala: statically access class object of another class

Tags: class, scala, reflection

I have two classes "ClassA" and "ClassB". I want to get the class object from the ClassA * and apparently I cannot do it.

```
class ClassA {
  ClassB.getClass() // <-- won't compile
}
class ClassB {
}
```

The only way would be to instantiate the specific class and call the getClass() from the newly created object. But I really don't want to create a new object for this!

```
class ClassA {
  new ClassB().getClass() // <-- compiles, but I don't want to create a new object!
}
class ClassB {
}
```

In Java this is straight forward. What's the problem with Scala doing the same?

*For context, I ultimately would like to obtain the FQCN of ClassB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classOf[ClassB]` will give you the Class object of ClassB.

Answer (score 3):

Here is working example:

```
class ClassA {
  val bClass = classOf[ClassB]
}
class ClassB {
}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(new ClassA().bClass/*<- here you got java.lang.Class object*/.getName())
  }
}
```

Scala 2.11.1 compiles ClassA to:

```
@ScalaSignature(bytes="...")
public class ClassA {
  private final Class<ClassB> bClass = ClassB.class;
  public Class<ClassB> bClass() { return this.bClass; }
}
```